# Cannot ping some PC on VPN

Tags: vpn, ping

I've set up VPN network between office and shop. Everything seems to be ok except for the fact that I can ping simple devices only. For example, we have scales with TCP/IP interface. So, from the office I can ping scales, that are on the shop network. But I cannot ping Linux Pcs there. And vice versa. I can ping even routers, where I set up permissive rules.

I believe, there is some network setting, that makes PCs drop packets from VPN network. Can you please help me find which one?

Office network is 192.168.254.x, shop one is 192.168.1.x.

I think this is because a PC on 192.168.1.0/24 does not accept packets from 192.168.254.0/24 on the PPP interface, which is Internet. Is there any option to allow this?

Comment: Do you have iptables set up? It would be helpful if you show us your firewall rules.

Comment: There is no iptables on the PCs I cannot ping.

Comment: What are you using for VPN? Are you doing NAT in one direction? You will not be able to ping hosts behind NAT.

Comment: I am perfectly capable of pinging hosts behind NAT. The problem was that the default gateway was not set in those machines I couldn't ping. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was, that the default gateway on those Linux machines was not correctly set. So packets went to the machine, but could never get back.